# Setting a maximum quantity value with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation, math, shopify

I have this javascript to prevent quantity fields going below 1. What I would like to do is make sure the maximum quantity is 10 and can't go below 1.

```
/**
   * When using the quantity selector, this can be used to decrease the quantity (be ensuring it won't be lower than 1)
   */

}, {
  key: '_decreaseQuantity',
  value: function _decreaseQuantity(event, target) {
    target.nextElementSibling.value = Math.max(parseInt(target.nextElementSibling.value) - 1, 1);
  }

  /**
   * When using the quantity selector, this can be used to increase the quantity
   */

}, {
  key: '_increaseQuantity',
  value: function _increaseQuantity(event, target) {
    target.previousElementSibling.value = parseInt(target.previousElementSibling.value) + 1;
  }

  /**
   * Make sure the quantity does not go below when manually changed
   */

}, {
  key: '_validateQuantity',
  value: function _validateQuantity(event, target) {
    target.value = Math.max(parseInt(target.value) || 1, 1);
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replicating what you already did to keep the value from going below 1 is enough.

```js
{
  key: '_decreaseQuantity',
  value: function _decreaseQuantity(event, target) {
    target.nextElementSibling.value = Math.max(parseInt(target.nextElementSibling.value) - 1, 1);
  }

  /**
   * When using the quantity selector, this can be used to increase the quantity
   */

}, {
  key: '_increaseQuantity',
  value: function _increaseQuantity(event, target) {
    target.previousElementSibling.value = Math.min(parseInt(target.previousElementSibling.value) + 1, 10); // Added check
  }

  /**
   * Make sure the quantity does not go below when manually changed
   */

}, {
  key: '_validateQuantity',
  value: function _validateQuantity(event, target) {
    target.value = Math.min(Math.max(parseInt(target.value) || 1, 1), 10); // Added check
  }
}
```